# QT add object pointer in a pointer list

Tags: list, qt, pointers

I would like to add my `parentWidget` in a pointer list `QList<QGraphicsWidget*> items` from another class.

How can I add `parentWidget` in the `items` list and delete the `parentWidget` right after ?

Here is my code:

```
void DiagramScene::insertWidget(DiagramItem::DiagramType diagramtype)
{
   QGraphicsWidget * parentWidget = new QGraphicsWidget;

   //some code

   connect(this,SIGNAL(sendToItemList(QGraphicsWidget*)),diagramitem,SLOT(addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget*)));
   emit this->sendToItemList(parentWidget);
}
```

and this is my slot:

```
void DiagramItem::addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget* widget)
{
   items.append(widget);
}
```

My actual code gives me this by each `insertWidget` call :

first call: `items` = 1 item

second call: `items` = 3 items

third call: `items` = 6 items

fourth call: `items` = 10 items

Comment: You make a new connection every time `insertWidget` is called. The slot will be called for each connection you make. You don't even seem to need to connect a signal to a slot here. Just call the slot directly.

Comment: Yes thank you, that solved the problem